# How to get the selected node value from a tree region in Apex?

Tags: tree, oracle-apex-18.2

I need to get the value of a selected node (when double clicking on a node) in order to show different information in a Modal page that will be opened.
PD: I have already tried creating a page item and then asigned it in the field "Selected Node Page Item" of the tree but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

apex.jQuery("#t_TreeNav").treeView("option", "selectionChange", function(e){
console.log("Selection changed, value of selected node is " + apex.jQuery(this).treeView("getSelectedNodes")[0].label);
});

Comment: Please format your code and explain, why/how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The selected node is used when rendering the tree to "remember" what the user was looking at, and it is not saved dynamically:

> *This item is used to save tree state, by holding the value of the last
>   selected node. The value of the selected node can be saved to the
>   selected item via the node link attribute, or via a page process. When
>   the page is reloaded, the tree is opened to the selected node value.*

I use a "Selection Change [Tree]" dynamic action on the tree region, running the following JS (BasicTree is the static ID of the region, P1_NODE is the page item):

```
var id = apex.jQuery("#BasicTree div[role='tree']").treeView("getSelectedNodes")[0].id;
$s('P1_NODE', id);
```

Comment: how to search tree node using id?

Comment: unfortunately I don't know of a way to do so directly.
two options:
a. change the tree node item and then refresh the tree node using the "Tree - refresh" plugin
b. adding a secret "id" as one of the classes for the tree icons ("dummy_"||id as icon)